# Rails: Model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models, one called User and another called Recruiter.  What I would like to do is to be able to create a scope that searches users and returns the results so recruiters can see them.  But I'm not sure how to go about setting up the association.  I made a through association between users and recruiters and created a new join table called recruiter_users but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.

1) What the best way to make the association between the 2 models 
2) how exactly would I display the user results in the recruiters view?

```
  class RecruiterUser < ApplicationRecord

  # this is a join model between recruiters and users
  belongs_to :recruiter
  belongs_to :user




class User < ApplicationRecord

  # creates association with recruiters model through the join table recruiter_users
  has_many :recruiter_users
  has_many :recruiters, through: :recruiter_users



class Recruiter < ApplicationRecord

  # creates association with users model through the join table recruiter_users
  has_many :recruiter_users    
  has_many :users, through: :recruiter_users
```

Comment: Without knowing more about what you're trying to do, the associations you have shown here are perfectly valid. Is there something that's not working for you the way you're wanting?

Comment: how would I display the user results in the recruiters view?

Answer (score 0):

Again, without having more details about your application, if all you need to do is display the `User`s associated with a particular `Recruiter` in a view, it could be as simple as this:

```
<% @recruiter.users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.whatever_attribute %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want your average run of the mill many to many association:

```
class User
  has_many :recruitments
  has_many :recruiters, 
    through: :recruitments
end

class Recruiter
  has_many :recruitments
  has_many :recruited_users, 
    through: :recruitments,
    source: :user
end

class Recruitment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :recruiter
end
```

You don't have to name your join models a + b. If there is a more descriptive name of what the relation is use it.

this would let you iterate through the users recruited by a recruiter by:

```
@recruiter = Recruiter.includes(:recruited_users).find(params[:id])

<% @recruiter.recruited_users.each do |user| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```